# Detect Mobile Device - YouTube JS API

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Using the standard JS API from YouTube I have implemented a video that I will make auto-play on desktop (hiding all controls) and then show custom controls.

On mobile obviously I cannot auto-play and so wish to just show the standard YouTube video with controls (and some other bits).

What's the best method to detect devices that don't support non-fullscreen non-auto-play video embeds?

I'd like to avoid device width solutions and REGEX user-agent sniffing isn't a great solution.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

I recently needed to detect android browsers in an application that i'd built.
I don't know how do i to detect another devices, but you can try the same idea.

To fix my problem, i used:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
    // Do something!
    // Redirect to Android-site?
    window.location = 'http://android.davidwalsh.name';
}
```

Hope it help.